# Mixing html elements with JSF components reduces size JSF component tree

Tags: performance, jsf, components, viewstate

I would like to know what JSF component tree contains inside of it, only JSF components or both JSF components and html elements. I checked component tree from debugging window and saw all html elements were grey color in component tree, what does it mean? Since I couldn't see size of each component/element so it's difficult to come up with any decision, anybody can tell me, thanks?

If html elements (greyed out) are not part of component tree then we can replace JSF components with html elements for reducing component tree size, is that true?

Comment: JSF components are basically rendered as html elements and this is what you'll see in the browser. This is what happens to most server-side components when they get rendered on the client-side.

Comment: and component tree belongs to server-side..and what it contains here...only JSF components?

Comment: It doesn't matter you can always mix html with specific JSF components.

Comment: I'm learning JSF intensively for tweaking performance so general answer without explaining why is not considered as ... an answer at all, please give me an right to the point answer then I will accept it, thanks

Comment: All JSF components are parsed into plain html to render in the browser which you could see in the page view source. If you declare one <h:commandButton> in your xhtml then you will have one HtmlCommandButton the component tree. So if you are using html <table> directly in your xhtml instead of <h:panelGrid> which will be parsed to html <table> tag then obviously you wont have HtmlPanelGrid instance in component and you will save parsing time of <h:panelGrid> to html.

Comment: Thanks for your informative comment Ganji, so the component tree contains both parsed-to-html JSF components and html elements right?